# generating uuid in PostgresSQL when importing a csv or text file

Tags: postgresql, csv, uuid, pgadmin-4

I need to import a text or csv file in pgadmin3 or 4 for a specified table in my database. I have all the required information for the table except for the uuid. I have scripted a single file in and generated the uuid using `SELECT md5(random()::text || clock_timestamp()::text)::uuid`, but how do I do this for a text file or csv file that im importing into the table?

Comment: Cannot you first import it, then add a column and generate values?

Comment: This is in a table that is already created so I cannot do that.

Comment: Then this question is about csv file processing and is tangential to postgresql 

Comment: could i use the insert script i generated for a single file to somehow copy the data in the csv or txt file and use the uuid creation line from my original post to generate the uuids?

Comment: Define a default value and don't include the column in the `COPY` command

Comment: How would I define the default value? Where within the COPY command would I place uuid generate command?

Comment: You would not put it anywhere - just skip the column and the default value would be used.